# How can I make a vocal-based sound effect on OS X

Tags: macos, audio

I want to make a simple vocal-based sound effect on OS X.

What software can I use to do this? Is it easy to do with Garage Band? Is there a specific tutorial I should look at?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a vocoder?  See this if you're not sure.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hqvvNcvenU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a vocoder you are looking for, the only one I know of for mac is a module inside of Propellerhead Software's Reason (a great piece of software, but not a bargain - $499).  If you go this route, you can record your vocoder track and import it into GarageBand (or Logic).  http://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/index.cfm

Comment: As a saide note, Audacity is free, open source and does the job regarding the Vocoder effect, have a look here: http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Vocoder

Answer (score 2):

This may not be what you were asking, but you can open a terminal and type

say -o out.aiff "Hello World"

to write a sound file with text-to-speech output in it.